# how to make login flow for ipad and then present UISplitViewController - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I am using storyboard - xcode 5.0 and targeting ios 5.0+
 [image]

I have tried to launch UISplitViewController when Login/signup button is pressed and in UISplitViewController - Detail Controller i want to provide **logout** functionality as well.

I have tried Login/Signup ----> Master/Detail UISplitViewController but Apple Docs says UISplitViewController must be rootView Controller.

How to achive such a comman functionality?
I have search lot of posts on SO but none of them are clear.